# Better way of implementing Spring webservices

Tags: java, web-services, spring

I found its very difficult and redundant to wirte XML configuration to define spring webservice.
Example:
To Expose WSDL

```
    <bean id="addService" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition"
    p:portTypeName="add" p:locationUri="http://localhost:9080/WebServiceExample/"
    p:requestSuffix="-request" p:responseSuffix="-response">
        <property name="schema">
          <bean class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema" p:xsd="classpath:/WEB-INF/Addition.xsd" />
        </property>
        <property name="targetNamespace" value="addition.apps" />
```

and for JAXB context (defining marshaller and unmarshallers)

```
    <bean class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.GenericMarshallingMethodEndpointAdapter">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
        <property name="contextPath" value="apps.addition"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="wsTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">
        <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
        <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    </bean>
```

Let say, I need to implement 100 webservices in an application then what is the complexity involved. 

Can you please suggest me the proper approach to reduce configuration for this.Any annotation driven approach?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you looked at JAX-WS or must it be Spring?

Answer (score 1):

JAX-WS and JAXB both support annotations, and are supported by Spring Framework

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html

JAX-WS has (long ago) a reference Implementation using Spring configuration

http://www.springsource.org/node/396

More on JAX-WS 
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jax_ws_2/

Spring WS has it's own annotation support as well

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html

More about the difference between Spring WS and JAX-WS

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?77968-Spring-WS-vs-JAX-WS

if you like Spring WS because of the "contract first" approach, look at this one

http://rphgoossens.wordpress.com/2011/02/20/developing-a-contract-first-jax-ws-webservice/

Answer (score 0):

Springboot provide support for creating webservice easy way.
It reduce the configuration part like spring mvc(xml configuration).

https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot

https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/